# Ruby: Checking a value within a csv list of multiple arrays and showing which array has that value

Tags: ruby

```
    require 'csv'

    ########
    ## Ask for Serial number
    ########
    serial_number = ask("Product serial number?")
    serial_number = serial_number.to_s
    serial_number = serial_number.upcase
    stamp_date= Time.now
    old = Time.now.to_i

    ##########
    ##Check if file exist in directory
    ##########
    if File.exist? ('procedures/Serial.csv')
        #########
        #Check serial number exist in CSV
        #########
        file = File.open("procedures/Serial.csv","r")
        items = []
        while (line1 = file.gets)
            arr = line1.split(',')
            items.push ({"Product Number": arr[0],"Time Used": arr[1], "Time in Secs": arr[2]})
        end
        file.close
        checklist = items.inspect
        puts checklist
        repeat = checklist.include?serial_number
        puts repeat

        if repeat == true
            #prompt("Exist")
 #Thinking I should insert that part of code here to check if the value exist within the csv file.

            exit
        else
            #prompt("Does not exist")        
            ########
            #If serial number does not exist, create it within the csv
            ########

            ######
            #Append value into the csv
            #######
            CSV.open("procedures/Serial.csv","a+") do |csv|
                csv << [ serial_number, stamp_date, old]
            end

            ###############
            ## Read the file
            ###############
            file = File.open("procedures/Serial.csv","r")

            items = []

            while (line = file.gets)
                arr = line.split(',')
                items.push ({"Product Number": arr[0],"Time Used": arr[1], "Time in Secs": arr[2]})
            end
            file.close
            puts items.inspect
        end

    else 
        #######
        ##Insert Serial number into file
        #######
        CSV.open("procedures/Serial.csv","wb") do |csv|
            csv << [ serial_number, stamp_date, old]
        end

        ###############
        ## Read the file
        ###############
        file = File.open("procedures/Serial.csv","r")

        items = []

        while (line = file.gets)
            arr = line.split(',')
            items.push ({"Product Number": arr[0],"Time Used": arr[1], "Time in Secs": arr[2]})
        end
        file.close
        puts items.inspect
    end
```

Currently, I am asking the user to input a value and checking that value exist within the csv file in the first column or in this case...arr[0] in every array.

I was wondering if anyone know how to pull that specific array out from the list of array in the csv file? The goal is to pull that specific array out and replace the value within the array with a new Time.

Comment: I'd recommend using rubys CSV library to read the CSV also, instead of doing `split(',')` which could break on e.g. escaped commas like `\,`

Comment: What your'e doing is either updating or creating a new timestamp, right?  Doesn't need to do anything else?  I would use `OptionParser` to get the serial number from the command line, read the file, search & replace/add in memory, and then rewrite the entire file.  You can't just update the timestamp in place on disk because the record length is variable and might change.

Comment: @Tom Yeah. I am just updating a new timestamp. I am also trying to find how long that serial number has been checkout for when it was first time stamp.